# DataFrame Corr(), do not find the column index

Tags: python, correlation

I tried to find corr between `citable documents per person` and `Energy Supply per Capita`, (Pearson's correlation)

1. so I create a table `Top15`, whose columns =

   `Index(['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations',
              'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply',
              'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008',
              '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', 'popu',
              'citable documents per person'],
             dtype='object')`

but when I write `Top15.corr()`, results only show correlation among

```
['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations',
           'Citations per document', 'H index', 
            '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008',
           '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
```

There are no `citable documents per person` and `Energy Supply per Capita`

2. Then I create a new table `df`

[image]

but when I write `df.corr()`, I get `_`, then I also tried `df.corr(method='pearson')`, but get the same result `_`

3. I search online and find this method:

   `from scipy.stats import pearsonr
   corr, _ = pearsonr(Top15['citable documents per person'], Top15['Energy Supply per Capita']) 
   print(corr)`

This works, but I do not understand the expression `corr, _` , why `,_`?

Could someone help me and explain 1. why method one and two fail? why some variables disappear in corr results?  2. what is `,_` in method 3?
Thank you.

Comment: `corr` only considers numeric columns. Are you sure your columns are all numeric?

Comment: _ means ignore it, e.g. for k, v in dict.items() will create an iter for key and value, if you dont caare about the value you usse for k,_ in dict.items() and the _ will be ignored

Comment: @ling I think this is a question from Coursera's assignment and I have done this sometimes ago, here some of the columns are of type **object** , you have to convert them to **numeric** using something like pandas **to_numeric** .

Comment: Thank you! yes, the they are not numeric type, corr works after changing the type.

Comment: @E.Serra thank you for the explanation. Understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corr only considers numeric columns. Are you sure your columns are all numeric? – BallpointBen

_ means ignore it, e.g. for k, v in dict.items() will create an iter for key and value, if you dont caare about the value you usse for k,_ in dict.items() and the _ will be ignored – E.Serra

I think this is a question from Coursera's assignment and I have done this sometimes ago, here some of the columns are of type object , you have to convert them to numeric using something like pandas to_numeric . – Snehil